# Drupal 8: custom form is not displaying if logged in as administrator

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In D8, I want to show a custom form in the custom generated block. I've created the required custom module and assigned the block with a region. Nothing is showing into that region at front end if logged in as Administrator or Authenticated user. However, the form is coming if I see the front end as anonymous user. Below is my code. Need your help.

## /src/Plugin/Block/DashBlock.php

```
namespace Drupal\dash\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'Dash' Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "dash_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Dash block"),
 *   category = @Translation("Dash"),
 * )
 */
class DashBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\dash\Form\WorkForm');
    return $form;
  }
}
```

## /src/Form/WorkForm.php

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\dash\Form\WorkForm.
 */
namespace Drupal\dash\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class WorkForm extends FormBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'dash_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['employee_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Employee Name:'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['employee_mail'] = array(
      '#type' => 'email',
      '#title' => t('Email ID:'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Register'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
    );
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    drupal_set_message($this->t('@emp_name ,Your application is being submitted!', array('@emp_name' => $form_state->getValue('employee_name'))));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The block visibility can be managed in adminitration views, go to *Home > Administration > Structure > Block layout* and select the region/block to edit and click *Configure*.

From there you can restrict the block visibility to specific user roles (content type, language, path as well). In your case it must be that `"Anonymous user"` is selected while you don't want it to.

Just unselect/select the proper roles for which your block to be restricted to, then save.

[image: example]

Comment: All checkboxes are unchecked under Roles as you said. However, still anonymous can see the form while administrator/authenticated users are unable. Mysterious huh?

Comment: Yep mysterious.. maybe some role restriction apply but programmatically ? I would search within code chunks dealing with user roles conditions and such. I'd also check whether the form is built for authenticated users or not.

Comment: like by printing something when the form is supposed to be built. Can you check and tell if the form is actually built for authenticated users ?

Comment: I will place entire yml file content by Monday 6th Jan 2020.

Comment: One thing I noticed. When I used `$form['#theme'] = 'dash_form';` and `function dash_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){ ... }` to customize the form theme, and in the `twig` file under `templates` I wrote "BlaBlaBla", the content BlaBlaBla appeared both on the screen of anonymous and admin users

Comment: Ok , good to know. This probably means that this is your theme that is actually hiding the form to authenticated users.